# Forcing frontend login with UI switch

Tags: login, wp-login-form

Is there a way to force log-in even for *viewing* a WordPress blog that the blog's owner can turn on and off by themselves?

I can hardcode it in the template's `header.php` like so:

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
   wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
   exit;
}
```

but this can't be influenced from the blog's administration page.

There is the [force user login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-user-login/) plugin, but it doesn't work in 3.x blogs. I'll try to patch the plugin for 3.x, but suggestions for other (native?) methods are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple to implement, you could put this into functions.php if you want it tied to a theme, or else create your own plugin from this:

```
add_action('init','my_force_login');
function my_force_login(){
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() &&  !in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) ) {
        $force_login=get_option('my_force_login');
        if($force_login){
            wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work you will then need to create an option (either a theme option if this is to be tied to a theme, or otherwise an [extra option in an appropriate WordPress page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

In the above, I am assuming there is an option with name 'my_force_login' with value true/false (or 1/0) which determines if the redirect should take effect.

The redirect applies to all logged-out users to all pages except the login/register page.

Comment: You can add custom options to the WP backend easily? Cool, wasn't aware of that. Thanks, I will try this out!

Comment: Yup, [see the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). The examples will be particularly helpful.